# will googlebot index my site?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

in my robots.txt file, I have the following line

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Disallow: /

User-agent:GoogleBot
Disallow: /

Sitemap: http://mydomain.com/sitemapindex.xml

I know that if I put the first 4 lines , googlebot won't index the sites, but what if I put the last line **Sitemap: http://mydomain.com/sitemapindex.xml**, will googlebot be able to index the site?

Thanks,

Comment: this is a question for google, not a programming question

Comment: I agree not programming but no harm for a programmer to know this.

Answer (score 4):

I tested your robots.txt against my own domain (which has a sitemap entry for every page) and Googlebot and Googlebot-Mobile returned that they were Disallowed access.

Based on this - I would say the robots.txt file takes precedence over any sitemaps.

Plus, logically speaking - if you block the entire domain, the bot is disallowed access to the sitemap. The sitemap entry just tells crawlers where to find your sitemap - not their authorization to access it.

Even if you allowed the sitemap, I don't think bots would crawl your site - sitemaps are designed more for telling the bot how often to crawl your site, not what they are allowed to crawl.

Answer (score 2):

No I dont think Google will do that. Its actually a question of Good bot and Bad bot. Even if you add a robots.txt file to restrict some area Bots can still crawl. Its actually a question of Yes or No. robots.txt is just like a warning board and not a security wall.

Comment: Agreed with security concerns, OP might not know bad bot scenarios if he wanted to keep his site "off the map" completely.

Answer (score 1):

googlebot will not even be able to touch the sitemapindex.xml

- the robots.txt is a crawler directive.
- the sitemap.xml is fetched via the googlebot crawler.
- googlebot will not access the sitemapindex.xml
- no crawl coverage, no indexing, no SERP listing

you can test this with google webmaster tools robots.txt verification tool and fetch as googlebot (in the labs section) feature.

Comment: You should correct the typos alittle, but +1 for your clarity on the terms.